# Find the degree of the function

Tags: complex-analysis

> Suppose $f$ is an entire function such that $|f(z)|<a+b|z|^{0.5}$ for all $z$.Then what is the degree of $f(z)$? Options are
>
> **1.** $f$ is a constant function.
>
> **2.** $f$ can be a polynomial of degree $1$
>
> **3.** $f$ can be a polynomial of degree $2$
>
> **4.** $f$ can be a polynomial of degree $3$

**My effort:**

Since $f(z)$ is an entire function its derivative is also an entire function.Now $|f'(z)|<b|z|^{-0.5}$. But the R.H.S. of this in-equation is not entire. So $f(z)$ is a constant function.

Am I right?

Comment: When putting in exponents, make sure to put brackets around the entire exponent.  For example, $x^{2k+1}$ is x^{2k+1} and NOT x^2k+1

Comment: Can we use Liouville's Theorem?

Comment: Liouvlle's Theorem tells "A bounded and entire function is constant."Here in the given inequation contains z.Then how can we use the theorem?